# How to set visibility criteria in Asp.net Core 6 MVC web forms

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, visible

I have this

```
<div class="mb-3">
                                        <label asp-for="DeliveryDt" class="control-label"></label>
                                        <input asp-for="DeliveryDt" type="text" class="datepicker form-control" autocomplete="off" autofocus="true" readonly />
                                        <span asp-validation-for="DeliveryDt" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    </div>
```

i want to hide this field from my razor view.but i have no idea.
In Asp.net simple we Visible = 'False' ,but this is not working in .Net core 6 MVC
please show me idea except $('#DeliveryDt').hide();

I have tried this $('#DeliveryDt').hide();
this is working but it only hides textbox ,label is still dispalying as it is.

please share some idea except jquery or javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use css `display: none`:

```
<div class="mb-3" style="display:none">
    <label asp-for="DeliveryDt" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="DeliveryDt" type="text" class="datepicker form-control" autocomplete="off" autofocus="true" readonly />
    <span asp-validation-for="DeliveryDt" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

If you want to optional control the div visible by backend, you could define a property in your model.

1. Model

   ```
   public class YourViewModel
    {
         public DateTime DeliveryDt { get; set; }
         public bool ShowDeliveryDt { get; set; } = true; // Default to true, set to false to hide
    }
   ```
2. View

- use if statement

  ```
   @if (Model.ShowDeliveryDt)
   {
       <div class="mb-3">
            <label asp-for="DeliveryDt" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="DeliveryDt" type="text" class="datepicker form-control" autocomplete="off" autofocus="true" readonly />
            <span asp-validation-for="DeliveryDt" class="text-danger"></span>
       </div>
   }
  ```
- Or you can use css

  ```
   <div class="mb-3 @(Model.ShowDeliveryDt ? "" : "hidden-field")">
       <label asp-for="DeliveryDt" class="control-label"></label>
       <input asp-for="DeliveryDt" type="text" class="datepicker form-control" autocomplete="off" autofocus="true" readonly />
       <span asp-validation-for="DeliveryDt" class="text-danger"></span>
   </div>
   @section Scripts {
       @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
       <style>
           .hidden-field {
               display: none;
           }
       </style>
   }
  ```

3. Controller

   ```
   public IActionResult YourActionMethod()
   {
       var model = new YourViewModel
       {
           // Set other properties as necessary
           ShowDeliveryDt = false // Set to false to hide the field
       };

       return View(model);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In this case if you want to hide the entire div (label, textbox, validation message) you can do the following:

```
<div id="DeliveryDtGroup" class="mb-3">
    <label asp-for="DeliveryDt" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="DeliveryDt" type="text" class="datepicker form-control" autocomplete="off" autofocus="true" readonly />
    <span asp-validation-for="DeliveryDt" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Then using jQuery, you can call the following:

```
$('#DeliveryDtGroup').hide();
```

Comment: Is it possible without jQuery?
like we use in asp.net c# visible=false

Comment: Unfortunately no, you cannot control the visibility of HTML elements from Controller code directly in ASP.NET MVC. If you want to control the visibility from the Controller, you can pass values to ViewBag or ViewData, or even to the Model, and check these values in your View and set the visibility accordingly.

Comment: No problem, @Renas answer above is an excellent demonstration of how to achieve what I mentioned in my comment

Comment: your Answer is also right.it is working in a perfect way.thank you for help and answer all my queries

Answer (score 0):

var DeliveryDt= '@Model.DeliveryDt'.toLowerCase() == 'true';

Note : replace the above with your condition to hide the control

```
    // Hide or show the field based on the value
   if (!DeliveryDt) {
        document.getElementById('DeliveryDt').closest('.form-group').style.display = 'none';
    }
```

In the above case I want to hide the control, when @Model.DeliveryDt is false